# What are the different colours?

Tags: support

Sometimes the numbers are green (guess that means that there is at least one answer to a question). Sometimes the background of the number is also green. Sometimes the background of the entire field of a question (plus the stats) is yellow.

What the heck do all those colours mean? I checked the help, but couldn't find an explanation. Can someone give me some pointers, pls.?

[image: what's with the colours]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these topics:

- [Why do some questions in question lists have a yellow background?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11253/139866)
- [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281740/49942)

I found these by [searching the meta.stackexchange.com site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=yellow+background).

In summary:

- Yellow background -- the topic has one of your "favourite tags"
- Green number -- the topic has at least one answer
- Green background -- the topic has an accepted answer